# Calculate Time Between Orders By Customer ID

Tags: python, pandas

I have following Porblem:

I want to calculate the time between orders for every Customer in Days.
My Dataframe looks like below.

```
    CustID   OrderDate   Sales
5   16838   2015-05-13  197.00  
6   17986   2015-12-18  224.90  
7   18191   2015-11-10  325.80  
8   18191   2015-02-09  43.80   
9   18191   2015-03-10  375.60
```

I found following piece of Code but I cant get it to work.

```
(data.groupby('CustID')
    .OrderDate
    .apply(lambda x: (x-x.min).days())
    .reset_index())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the date column to a datetime first and also put it in chronological order. This code should dot he trick:

```
data.OrderDate = pd.to_datetime(data.OrderDate)
data = data.sort_values(by=['OrderDate'])
data['days'] = data.groupby('CustID').OrderDate.apply(lambda x: x.diff())
```

Notice that this gives the days since the last order made by the customer. If the customer has not made a previous order then it will be returned as NaT.